# Double enter with a barvode-scanner?

Tags: barcode, enter

If you have a barcode-scanner and scans an EAN-code it scans the code and then make a ENTER. But I want my computer to make TWO ENTER when the scanner has scanned a code. How can I fix that? A little program in the background? Or is there already a program/code for this?

Please help.

Regards
Sebastian

Comment: When you say "makes an ENTER," do you mean that it simulates the keyboard "enter" key being pressed? As in, does the computer think that the barcode is a keyboard?

Comment: When you scan the EAN-code "1234" for example in notepad the computer inputs "1234" and then makes an ENTER. So yes, I think the computer take the scanner for a keyboard...

Comment: What kind of computer are you running this on? Mac? Windows? Linux?

Comment: I use Windows, Windows 7 to be more specefic...

Comment: Hmm ok. I'm unfortunately not a windows guy, so I probably won't be able to help. I'll see if I can find somebody who is a windows guy, though.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway. If you can ask someone else it would be fantastic...

Comment: OK, I punted to a friend who has some experience with external readers as keyboards. Hopefully he'll know something that I don't.